# Physical meaning of a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and its Jacobian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What exactly does it mean when it says:

For
\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{R}^2 &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3,\\
f\pmatrix{x\\ y} &= \pmatrix {xy\\ \sin(x+y)\\ x^{2} - y^{2}},\\
Jf\pmatrix{x\\ y}
&= \left[\matrix{y&x\\ \cos(x+y)&\cos(x+y)\\ 2x&-2y}\right].
\end{align*}
My question is, what does this physically mean?

And also, what does the first bit mean? We have a function of two variables that is represented by three separate expressions?

Comment: Does the first bit make more sense if you replace the $n$ by the correct numbers? The given function is $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$. When you say "what does this physically mean?" are you asking for a physical interpretation ... like an example from physics or something more along the lines of "how do you find $Jf$"?

Comment: Physical example. I'm a first year physics student, I'm just trying to get a head start on some of the mathematical topics for the 2013-2014 academic year (although I have a lot of interest in pure math).

how is this ${R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ ? f is represented with three seperate expressions (why?), and after the Jacobian is taken, we get a 3X2 matrix as a result.

Comment: The Jacobian is formed by the matrix columns $[f_x | f_y]$, that is the partial $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Like the derivative in one variable allows you to approximate a function by a degree one polynomial, the jacobian yields an affine approximation.

Answer (score 2):

The [*Jacobian*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobian.html) is made up of the partial in respect to $x$ and $y$ for each function as the columns of the matrix:

$$Jf{x \choose y} = \left[ \matrix {
f_x (xy) & f_y (xy) \\ 
f_x(\sin(x+y)) & f_y(\sin(x+y)) \\
f_x(x^2-y^2) & f_y(x^2-y^2) 
}
\right]= \left[ \matrix {
y&x \\
cos(x+y)&cos(x+y) \\
2x&-2y
}
\right]
$$

Comment: Nice and concise and directly to the point! +1

Comment: $+1$ from my pocket to our friend.

Comment: @BabakS.: Nice to see you and thank you my friend!

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines define your application $f$, which is here non-linear (sine function, quadratic terms ..). There is clearly a mistake in the first line: it is not $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, but $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$.

These two lines usually go together with a left bracket enclosing them, it reads: "We define the application named $f$, defined over $\mathbb{R}^2$ (vectors of two real numbers), and taking values in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (vectors of three real numbers). This application associates to any element $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, the element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by ... (the right member of the second line)".

The third part does not define $f$ per say. As Amzoti clearly explained, it is the Jacobian matrix of the corresponding application. In this case, if we denote formally:
$$
f\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\\ c \end{pmatrix}
$$
then the Jacobian of $f$ (provided it exists) would correspond to:
$$
Jf\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial a}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial a}{\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial b}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial c}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is it a sufficient explanation? I have to say, like the others, I don't know where to draw the line for "physical enough" :)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I think I'm understanding it a bit better. I'm still a bit confused by f having three expressions attached to it though. Does it mean to represent three vectors in $R^{2}$?

Comment: is $f\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}$ a linear transformation? Maybe that's what I'm not understanding?

Comment: @user6777 I'm not quite sure what you mean by "three expressions attached to it"? If you are refering to $(a,b,c)$, it is simply the value taken by $f$, which has three coordinates. Let's take another example; consider a 2D plane, and a cone which generatrix is orthogonal to that plane. Now let $g$ be the function that associates to any point on the cone, it's orthogonal projection on the plane. Then $g^{-1}$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, just like $f$. As I said in my first sentence, $f$ is not a linear transformation.

Comment: I', sorry, I'm not understanding, I'll start another question about  this.

Comment: Why start another question when you can point to what it is you don't understand right here? We're only here to help, just say what exactly isn't clear in the explanations you received?

Comment: Ok, $$ f\pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix {xy \\ sin(x+y)\\ x^{2} - y^{2}}  $$

What does this mean? We have a function of two variables, x and y, which is equal to $$\pmatrix {xy \\ sin(x+y)\\ x^{2} - y^{2}} $$

These three expressions are equal to three separate coordinates? What does that mean? What does a graph of this function look like? 

Because this is a function of two variables, the function is in 3D (I know this is a 2D function, but I don't really understand *why*).

Comment: For starters, you should think of $f$ as a function of _one variable_ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (two coordinates). Then, you can't think about the graph of $f$ as you could visualize a surface in 3D, this would be wrong; we don't have an equation like $z = f(x,y)$ here, $f$ takes _values_ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, not $\mathbb{R}$ like $z$ does. Really, think about the cone/plane projection thing I told you, it's easy to see.

Comment: Hang on, is $f\pmatrix{x \\ y} $ a vector valued function? 

If it IS, wouldn't that mean that it's in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Yes it is, and no that's not what it means; it means that it is in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Yes, here it happens that $n=3$. But if it is your way to "prove" that you can draw $f$ in 3D, I think we might be touching at the core of your misconception.

Comment: I think I've understood it. f(x,y) = (a,b,c) is a function that will turn two values in $R^{2}$ and give a result in $R^{3}$. The result is a vector field in $R^{3}$.

So, for example $f\pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix {xy \\ sin(x+y)\\ x^{2} - y^{2} \\ 4xy^{3}}$ would be a mapping of $R^{2}$ to $R^{4}$?

Comment: Exactly :) Just a small mistake in your first sentence: it's _turn ONE value in $\mathbb{R}^2$_. (Sorry for the delay in my answer)

Comment: Many thanks, it all makes sense now! I can't believe my book never actually mentioned this, it assumed I already knew what they were.